# SQL Error Msg: A SELECT INTO statement cannot contain a SELECT statement that assigns values to a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables, select, sql-insert

I get the error

> A SELECT INTO statement cannot contain a SELECT statement that assigns values to a variable

when I run the following lines of code on Microsoft SQL Server 2016. I am trying to use these codes to query multiple tables (with suffix after "EY_RCMTxn_20") from the server and then name the consolidated results as #RCMTxn. I am able to query multiple tables, but fail to name it #RCMTxn.

How can I resolve this error?

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #RCMTxn

DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @sql = ''
SELECT @sql = @sql +'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM ['+name+']'
INTO #RCMTxn
FROM sys.tables
WHERE name LIKE '%EY_RCMTxn_20%'
SET @sql = STUFF(@sql,1,15,'')
EXEC(@sql)
```

---

I used the below script suggested by @Charlieface create a local temp table named #RCMTxn outside and use it in the dynamic SQL. However, I fail to insert the data into the temp table. "752277 rows affected" when I run the script, but it returns zero row when I run "SELECT * FROM #RCMTxn".

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #RCMTxn;
CREATE TABLE #RCMTxn(
    MemberAccountNo VARCHAR(8),
    CardHolderNo VARCHAR(2),
    ActivityDate Date,
    Clubhouse NVARCHAR(255),
    Complex NVARCHAR(255)
)

DECLARE @sep nvarchar(100) = '
UNION ALL
';

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = '
SELECT *
INTO #RCMTxn
FROM (
' +
STUFF((
    SELECT @sep + 'SELECT * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(name) + '
'
    FROM sys.tables
    WHERE name LIKE '%EY_RCMTxn_20%'
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
  ).value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'), 1, LEN(@sep), '')
+ '
) t;
';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;

SELECT * FROM #RCMTxn
```

Comment: could you please clarify what you want to achieve with this strange dynamic SQL ?

Comment: The error is pretty clear. What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: @Sergey, sorry for the confusion. I am trying to use these codes to query multiple tables and then name the consolidated results as #RCMTxn.

Comment: @cheunghm4532, what is your SQL Server version?

Comment: @Zhorov SQL Server 2016

Comment: @HoneyBadger, I am trying to use these codes to query multiple tables (with suffix after "EY_RCMTxn_20") from the server and then name the consolidated results as #RCMTxn. I am able to query multiple tables, but fail to name it #RCMTxn.

Comment: If your strange SQL works otherwise, can't you just do a separate `select @sql as XXX INTO #RCMTxn` before exec?

Comment: What exactly do you expect the table #RCMTxn to contain? The resultset generated by your dynamic SQL?

Comment: @JamesZ, I tried but then I got the error mentioned above once I add the line "INTO #RCMTxn".

Comment: Not in the same statement, like I said, a **separate** select, before exec.

Comment: @SMor, I have around 50 tables in server, all named like "EY_RCMTxn_202203", "EY_RCMTxn_202204", etc. With the codes above I was able to union them all into one table. I want to store this table with the select into statement, but I encountered an error. Basically, when I add the line "INTO #RCMTxn" before "FROM", I get the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you wanted the `INTO` inside the dynamic SQL.

Also:

- You need to escape the table names properly
- Use `nvarchar(max)` for dynamic SQL
- Do not use `SET @var +=` to aggregated. Use `STRING_AGG` or `FOR XML` to aggregate.

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #RCMTxn;

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = '
SELECT *
INTO #RCMTxn
FROM (
' +
(
    SELECT STRING_AGG(
'SELECT * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(name), '
UNION ALL
'      )
    FROM sys.tables
    WHERE name LIKE '%EY_RCMTxn_20%'
) + '
) t;
';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

For older versions of SQL Server, you can use this:

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #RCMTxn;

DECLARE @sep nvarchar(100) = '
UNION ALL
';

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = '
SELECT *
INTO #RCMTxn
FROM (
' +
STUFF((
    SELECT @sep + 'SELECT * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(name) + '
'
    FROM sys.tables
    WHERE name LIKE '%EY_RCMTxn_20%'
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
  ).value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'), 1, LEN(@sep), '')
+ '
) t;
';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Alternatively, you can create the table outside and do a normal `INSERT`

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #RCMTxn;

CREATE TABLE #RMCTxn (Column1 ...);

DECLARE @sep nvarchar(100) = '
UNION ALL
';

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = '
INSERT #RMCTxn (Column1 ...)
' +
STUFF((
    SELECT @sep + 'SELECT * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(name) + '
'
    FROM sys.tables
    WHERE name LIKE '%EY_RCMTxn_20%'
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
  ).value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'), 1, LEN(@sep), '')
+ '
;
';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

---

Note that whatever it is that you are doing with temp tables could probably be done without.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I got below error msg when running your script: "'STRING_AGG' is not a recognized built-in function name." and "Must declare the scalar variable "@sql"." I am using SQL Server 2016 version.

Comment: OK added one for older versions also

Comment: Thanks! It runs without error with the older version script. However, how do you call the table. I try "SELECT * FROM #RCMTxn" but it says "Invalid object name '#RCMTxn'".

Comment: This is because you are selecting *outside* the dynamic SQL. For that to work you need to do `CREATE TABLE` outside first, after `DROP`. Then remove `INTO`. This is one of the reasons I said not to bother with temp tables at all. Just do `SELECT ... FROM` inside the dynamic SQL and it will give you the data

Comment: as suggested, I have create a temp table outside (see the updated script above), but I fail to insert the data in the temp table as it returns zero row when I run "SELECT * FROM #RCMTxn". As per the reason why I insist to use temp tables: I need to join many other tables to #RCMTxn for calculations. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: See latest edit

Comment: You are my hero!

Answer (score 1):

Can you split your work into more steps? Like this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #RCMTxn

DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX);

SET @sql = ''
SELECT @sql = @sql +'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM ['+name+']'
FROM sys.tables
WHERE name LIKE '%EY_RCMTxn_20%';

SET @sql = STUFF(@sql,1,15,'')

SELECT @sql as sql
INTO #RCMTxn;

EXEC(@sql);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, after running the above lines of code. I am not able to query the #RCMTxn with the SELECT * FROM statement.